# Can't Insert data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I am stumped :(   I've done searches and have tried many variations but can't seem to pin point my problem so alas here I am.

- *First off I'm new at this and I am learning through web searches and experimentation so please before you rip me a new one for being a noob just keep in mind that I am a noob and have admitted it and would rather talk about my solution rather than anything else.*

**Project**: Trying to make a little web app that allows me to insert comic book information into a mysql database. I have built the form to accept the data and pass it to my php page which does the insert into mysql.

- This is a self app / This will not have exposure to the outside world / while I know and am currently developing data checks I need to get info into the DB before collection gets out of hand.

Here is the code that I currently have. I've tried so many variations that I don't know which way is up....

```
$idcomic_db = $_POST['idcomic_db'];
$publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
$comic_name = $_POST['comic_name'];
$comic_num = $_POST['comic_num'];
$comic_cover = $_POST['comic_cover'];
$price_paid = $_POST['price_paid'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];


$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `comic_info_db`.`comic_db` (`idcomic_db`, `publisher`, `comic_name`, `comic_num`, `comic_cover`, `price_paid`, `quantity`) VALUES ('$idcomic_db', '$publisher', '$comic_name', '$comic_num', '$comic_cover', '$price_paid', '$quantity')";
$mysql_con = mysqli_query($sql_insert, $con);
$error = mysqli_error($mysql_con);

?>

<!-- HTML Header Information  -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css">
<head>
    <title>Comic Database Results</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<!-- HTML Body Area -->

<body>
<?php

echo "$idcomic <br />";
echo "$publisher <br />";
echo "$comic_name <br />";
echo "$comic_num <br />";
echo "$comic_cover <br />";
echo "$price_paid <br />";
echo "$quantity <br />";
echo "<br />";
echo $sql_insert;
echo $error;
?>

<?php
// Close Connection
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I've got some code I was playing with to do checks against values but alot of the values are set in the form itself.

Also I was doing those echos at the end just to see the values coming over from the html form and I've also got some other code that is the connection info to the DB as well as the error (if there is one) and that comes back just fine.

Any help would be great. I apologize again if this is simple I can't seem to get it so I throw myself on the alter.

Comment: Can you post the table sql data structure - since you might insert string into ints fields according to your insert sql

Comment: Not getting an error but I don't think my code is setup to display the mysql side of stuff. when I echo the values and the string it displays correctly **INSERT INTO comic_db (idcomic_db, publisher, comic_name, comic_num, comic_cover, price_paid, quantity) VALUES ('1', 'Marvel Comics', 'The Superior Spider-Man', '1', 'original', '3.99', '1')** is what the values comes back to insert into db.

Comment: http://teknogeek.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/db.png  <-- copy of image screen shot of mysql table setup

Comment: I've also gone and made sure that the user I'm using for the DB has correct permissions and it shows that it has Global FULL access rights to all DBs

Comment: I also should note that I can communicate with the DB because on the form input page where I collect the data one of the values (idcomic_db) pulls what number the unique key is at and adds one then sets that value to the idcomic_db value getting passed. so I know my connection is good cause I can change that value in the db and get desired results in option field on html form. so I am totally stumped lol to say the least.

Comment: Is there a better way to error the INSERT message? just to see what mysql is telling the INSERT command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My connection statement was reversed.

```
($con, $sql_insert)
($sql_insert, $con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes for strings that contain variables (as in your INSERT query string in the "values" section)

Comment: Let me give it a shot and see. I would imagine I would need to escape each " since the whole statement starts with a "

Answer (score 0):

Since the $con should have the database selected already, all you need to do is tell it the table you want to input the values. The following string should work for you.

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO comic_tb (idcomic_db, publisher, comic_name, comic_num, comic_cover, price_paid, quantity) VALUES ('$idcomic_db', '$publisher', '$comic_name', '$comic_num', '$comic_cover', '$price_paid', '$quantity')";
```

Make sure all your fields and variables are correct.

Comment: Gave it a shot and still no go. also tried to add the ` in the columns section of things and that did do anything either :( ty for the help though